# What is the right way to store arrays in a RedShift table?

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift

I'm facing the following error while creating a table in Redshift:

```
Column "main.sales_metrics" has unsupported type "character varying[]".;
```

In a DataFrame schema it looks like this:

```
|-- sales_metrics: array (nullable = true)
     |-- element: string (nullable = true)
```

I was trying to declare the column like I ususlly do in PostgreSQL: `sales_metrics text[]` As I have read from the docs, PostgreSQL data types are not supported in Amazon Redshift.

Then how should I properly declare the `sales_metrics` column that stores `Array[String]` when creating a table in RedShift?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Redshift does not support arrays](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-datatypes.html), but there are some [JSON functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html) you can use. 
Basically you can store data as varchar and use json functions to query data

For example:

```
create temporary table sales_metrics (col1 varchar(20));
insert into sales_metrics values ('[1,2,3]');
```

then

```
select json_extract_array_element_text(col1, 2) from sales_metrics;
 json_extract_array_element_text
---------------------------------
 3
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @ittus's answer, note that Redshift is picky about how the array is stored.

```
         json_arrays          | is_valid_json_array
------------------------------+---------------------
 []                           | t
 ["a","b"]                    | t
 ["a",["b",1,["c",2,3,null]]] | t
 {"a":1}                      | f
 a                            | f
 {foo, bar}                   | f
 {"one", "two"}               | f
 [x,y,z]                      | f
 [1,2,]                       | f
```